# Multi-server monitor/auto restarter in python

Tags: python, linux, bash, restart

I have 2 server programs that must be started with the use of GNU Screen. I'd like to harden these servers against crashes with a Python based program that kicks off each screen session then monitors the server process. If the server process crashes, I need the python code to kill the extraneous screen session and restart the server with screen again.

I'm very new to python but I'm using this opportunity to teach myself. I'm aware this can be done in bash scripting. But I want to build on this code for future features, so it needs to be just python.

The pseudocode is as follows:

```
thread-one {
     While 1:
     start server 1 using screen
     wait for server to end
     end while
}

thread-two {
     While 1:
     start server 2 using screen
     wait for server to end
     end while
}
```

Comment: Are these actually threads?  Or are they child processes?

Comment: the python script (I would think) would need to be multi-threaded to handle the restarting of two separate programs independently. So they are threads that start child processes independently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"need to be multi-threaded to handle the restarting of two separate programs"

Don't see why.

```
import subprocess

commands = [ ["p1"], ["p2"] ]
programs = [ subprocess.Popen(c) for c in commands ]
while True:
    for i in range(len(programs)):
        if programs[i].returncode is None:
            continue # still running
        else:
            # restart this one
            programs[i]= subprocess.Popen(commands[i])
        time.sleep(1.0)
```

Comment: Wow, I'll spend the next hour dissecting that code for every drop of information I can glean from it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You really shouldn't run production software on a screen. If the server gets rebooted, how will You start it up? Manually?
Also I think that You are trying to re-invent the wheel. There are already pretty good tools that do the thing You need.

> [launchtool](http://freshmeat.net/projects/launchtool/) lets you run a
>   user-supplied command supervising its
>   execution in many ways, such as
>   controlling its environment, blocking
>   signals, logging its output, changing
>   user and group permissions, limiting
>   resource usage, restarting it if it
>   fails, running it continuously,
>   turning it into a daemon, and more.

.

> [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) is a free open source
>   utility for managing and monitoring,
>   processes, files, directories and
>   filesystems on a UNIX system. Monit
>   conducts automatic maintenance and
>   repair and can execute meaningful
>   causal actions in error situations.

Comment: Though the server is in use by my clients, it's not mission critical, it's a testing server for non-business use. The server programs, though they are important to keep up, wont kill anyone or cost anyone money if they die. The main purpose of this exercise is to create a useful program that I can extend in the future while learning python. I've found I learn best when I have a need to satisfy. There may be apps to do this, but that defeats the purpose.